# Ruby: Is there a way to create Ri documentation?

Tags: ruby, ri

I want to create some Ri documentation for a Ruby class I wrote. Is there a way to create ri documentation and how do you do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong direction. Google Rdoc.